# Is there a way to use COUNTIF for partial numerical matches within a given +/- range?

Tags: excel-formula, countif

I'm attempting to use COUNTIF to see if one numerical cell matches any other cells in a given numerical list. The issue is some of numbers in this list aren't correct, and may be off by a decimal or a final figure (i.e. 100.25 instead of 100.75, or 100 instead of 102).

Is there a way to use COUNTIF for a given range, where I could say "I want to see if this cell's contents match with anything in this list, with a cushion range of 5". So if the cell I was using was 100, and a number in the list was 103, it would still pop up as a match in my COUNTIF. Please help!

=COUNTIF(J:J, I2)

Would hope to see that a number off by +/- 5 would still show as a match in my COUNTIF formula.

Answer (score 2):

Use COUNTIFS:

```
=COUNTIFS(J:J,"<="&I2+5,J:J,">="&I2-5)
```

An example:

[image]

Comment: I've entered in the below formula (in my case ended up changing the +/- to 2) and I'm seeing "0" for my COUNTIFS result. I know this isn't right because I've manually gone through the comparison and have seen matches.

=COUNTIFS(J:J,"<="&I2+2,J:J,">="&I2-2)

Comment: Can you edit your question with the sample data you're using?

Comment: Unfortunately no, it's sensitive budget information (I know that doesn't help). What i can say, however, is that the specific cell that I'm checking against my list is concatenated, and is represented as "100:34". Had to concatenate because it was the only way to create a unique identifier for each particular entry.

Comment: And the +/- I need to keep in check is just for ONE of those concatenated numbers. I.e if it was "100:34", I'd like to create a match for 100(+/-2):34. Same can be said for the other number, i.e. 100:34(+/-2). Make sense?

Comment: 100:34 is not a number... Can you just make up some sample data and show the expected result?

Comment: The concatenated numbers make this a different question than the one you originally posed. That's important information - 100:25 is very different from 100.25. It will require a different solution, which is why editing your question with some mock sample data, the way it actually is, as well as the expected result, will help us provide the correct answer.